# Listen for keywords in serial communication

Tags: arduino

I have an Arduino-like device which interacts with computers via USB and it is also accessible via Bluetooth. My device has only one TX/RX pin so I would like to activate the TX/RX connection to the Bluetooth Module after a special event, read some values and re-enable the USB connection.

Is this possible?

The serial input comes in this format !mod2, !mod is the identifier and 2 is the value...

```
if (selection == 16)                     //activates bluetooth selection mode
          {
            digitalWrite(ledGreen, HIGH);
            Serial.begin(9600);                           //start serial connection    
            while (Serial.find("!mod") == false)              
            {
              delay(100);
            }

            short val = Serial.parseInt(); 
            Serial.end();                             //close the connection to bt module, re-enable usb
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With an Arduino Uno, when a (computer) program uses the serial port to communicate with the Arduino, the Arduino reboots. 
The same thing happens when you close the program.

You can't re-enable the USB connection because it will reboot your Arduino.

Comment: I'll try to store the value in EEPROM, reboot the device and transmit the data via USB afterwards.